# Setting the size of a Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-canvas

I have implemented the android FingerPaint API demo found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html), my problem is that I only want this to fill the top half of the screen so that I can add some other elements to the bottom such as a list view.

I'm finding it hard to work out how to go about doing this. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be a great help.

Comment: I suspect a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) would be suitable(1).  You might also rethink the GUI and put the controls on top of the drawing surface, using a [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)(1).  1) But I'm a newbie in Android layouts, so will wait to see what the experts say.  ;)